# Mismatched Array type (scala.Array vs Array) for an RDD[Array[String]]

Tags: scala, apache-spark, dataframe, rdd

I'm trying to convert a dataframe to an RDD[Array[String]] in spark and currently to do so, I use the following method:

```
case class Array[String](c0:Long, c1:Integer, c2:Long, c3:String, c4:Integer, c5:Integer, c6:Integer)

val newData = df.distinct.map {
  case Row(c0:Long, c1:Integer, c2:Long, c3:String, c4:Integer, c5:Integer, c6:Integer) => Array[String](c0:Long, c1:Integer, c2:Long, c3:String, c4:Integer, c5:Integer, c6:Integer)
}

val newRDD = newData.rdd
```

This gives me what appears to be a transformation from a dataframe to an RDD[Array[String]] - however when I wrap it up in a function; like so:

```
 def caseNewRDD(df: DataFrame): RDD[Array[String]] ={
    case class Array[String](c0:Long, c1:Integer, c2:Long, c3:String, c4:Integer, c5:Integer, c6:Integer)
    val newData = df.distinct.map {
      case org.apache.spark.sql.Row(c0:Long, c1:Integer, c2:Long, c3:String, c4:Integer, c5:Integer, c6:Integer) => Array[String](c0:Long, c1:Integer, c2:Long, c3:String, c4:Integer, c5:Integer, c6:Integer)
    }
    val newRDD = newData.rdd
    newRDD
  }
```

I get the following error:

> Expression of type
>   org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD[Array[scala.Predef.String]] doesn't conform
>   to expected type
>   org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD[scala.Array[scala.Predef.String]]

I'm guessing the Array type that I'm generating isn't conforming properly, but I cannot figure out why.

Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You cannot cast types in Scala like that.

```
case class Array[String](c0:Long, c1:Integer, c2:Long, c3:String, c4:Integer, c5:Integer, c6:Integer)
```

means: create *NEW* type `Array` with a type alias `String`. What you are trying to accomplish is:

```
def caseNewRDD(df: DataFrame): RDD[Array[String]] = {
  df.distinct.map {
    case Row(c0:Long, c1:Integer, c2:Long, c3:String, c4:Integer, c5:Integer, c6:Integer) => 
      Array(c0.toString, c1.toString, c2.toString, c3, c4.toString, c5.toString, c6.toString)
  }.rdd
}
```

That is - I explicitly convert my types to `String`s without actually creating new type.

Comment: I'm trying to test your solution, at first I got the error [Unable to find encoder for type stored in a Dataset.] So I imported the following [val sparkSession: SparkSession = ??? && import sparkSession.implicits._] -> now I get the error [scala.NotImplementedError: an implementation is missing]

Comment: I've just realised a SparkContext was used for the full script, so starting a SparkSession wouldn't work in this case - though I'm not sure how to implement your solution without one

Comment: okay so I've figured out the SparkSession error but my code is still crashing though I believe it may be for another reason unrelated to the function you've defined in your answer so I'm going to accept your solution.